# Unexpected delay when presenting UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` in a `UITableViewController`, but when the Controller tries to dequeue the custom cell, it will take a long time (like 2000ms).

This line of code causes the problem

```
KidsListTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"kidsReuseIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

The `KidsListTableViewCell` is a custom cell, which includes couple of `UIButton`s, some `UILabel`s to show the information. And two delegate methods. It shouldn't be that slow to render that view. By the way, all of the information in the custom cell is basically static.

The is the full code of the UITableViewController. I put the custom view and regular view in different sections and I don't think this causes the problem.

```
#import "KidDetailTableViewController.h"
#import "KidDetailHeaderTableViewCell.h"
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
#import "Helper.h"

@interface KidDetailTableViewController () <KidDetailHeaderCellDelegate>

@end

@implementation KidDetailTableViewController
{
    KidDetailHeaderTableViewCell *headerCell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"KidDetailHeader" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"kidDetail"];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"detailCell"];


    self.tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return 1;
            break;

        default:
            return 10;
            break;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if (!headerCell) {


            headerCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"kidDetail"];

            headerCell.delegate = self;


            // Keep the background color for the cell when select.
            headerCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

            headerCell.nicknameLabel.text = _kidNeedsToShow.nickname;

            NSString *kidFullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", _kidNeedsToShow.firstName, _kidNeedsToShow.midName, _kidNeedsToShow.lastName];

            kidFullName ? (headerCell.fullNameLabel.text = @"") : (headerCell.fullNameLabel.text = kidFullName);


            // Set thumb image or use default
            // if there isn't image, use default.
            ALAssetsLibrary *library = [ALAssetsLibrary new];
            [library assetForURL:_kidNeedsToShow.photoURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                [headerCell.avatarImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage]]];
            } failureBlock:nil];
            return headerCell;
        }
        else return headerCell;
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"detailCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        return 290;
    }
    else return 60;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        return 290;
    }
    else return 60;
}

- (void)didClickLeftButton:(UIButton *)leftButton {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

I tried to put dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier into a different thread, apparently it wouldn't work.

UPDATE: KidDetailHeaderTableViewCell.m

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
    [_avatarImage.layer setCornerRadius:_avatarImage.frame.size.width / 2];
    [_avatarImage.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    [_avatarImage.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [_avatarImage setClipsToBounds:YES];

}

- (IBAction)leftButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didClickLeftButton:)]) {
        [self.delegate didClickLeftButton:sender];
    }
}
- (IBAction)rightButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didClickRightButton:)]) {
        [self.delegate didClickRightButton:sender];
    }
}
```

KidDetailHeaderTableViewCell.h

```
@protocol KidDetailHeaderCellDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)didClickLeftButton:(UIButton *)leftButton;
- (void)didClickRightButton:(UIButton *)rightButton;

@end

@interface KidDetailHeaderTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak) id<KidDetailHeaderCellDelegate> delegate;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fullNameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *avatarImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nicknameLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ageText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ageLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *momentsStatistics;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *momentsLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *rightButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *leftButton;

@end
```

UPDATE 2:
screenshot of instrument 
[image: screenshot of instrument]

The code for set the height of the cell. I have two sections, the first section actually is only used for header, the height is 290.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        return 290;
    }
    else return 60;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code from `KidDetailHeaderTableViewCell`? (initializers, `-prepareForReuse`, -`awakeFromNib`)

Comment: @Moxy Updated. I only used awakeFromNib and set a UIImageView from square to round. I tried to get rid of it, didn't work.

Comment: Did you use Instruments to find the 2000ms duration?

Comment: Have you implemented a custom hight cell, using: tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: @Moxy I added the screenshot of instrument.

Comment: @OnikIV Yes I did and pasted the code

Comment: The 2000ms are with scrolling or only with the loading of the first cells?

Comment: @Moxy only for the first cell.

Comment: Could you please add the whole code in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: @Moxy I updated all the code of the controller

Answer (score 0):

One of my friend pointed out that problem was caused by the custom font (Yes! I used custom font in the custom view). I still not sure about why this causes the problem (the font named 'hero'), but hope this will help someone else.